# Sleep/Wake up mechanim between pThreads and POSIX process;

Tags: process, synchronization, pthreads, sleep, wakeup

I have a C process creating several pThreads. To sleep and wake the threads up I am using pThread conditions. However, I want to sleep the POSIX process in such a way that pThreads can wake it up. How can I do it?

Comment: I don't think you can make the whole process sleep and be waken up by it's own threads, if that's what you mean. The operating system can take care of the process scheduling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just referring to the initial thread in a multithreaded process (the one that begins at `main()`), then it's a thread much like any other, and can use the normal pthreads synchronisation primitives.

Comment: Hi,

I allways thought it was a process and not a thread. Any interesting web-based info / book I can read to this respect?

Thanks!

Comment: @a3mlord: Under POSIX, each schedulable thread of control in a process is a thread.  A process is a collection of one or more threads in the same address space.

Comment: @a3mlord: The only one I can think of off the top of my head is *Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment, Second Edition* which has a couple of chapters on threads.  But that's a bit dated now.